# Consecutive Sum of column x that relates to column y

Tags: r, dplyr

In my dataset the Volume count always starts at 1 with every new Day. Like that:

```
Particle_Size Titrant      Day    Volume_titrant   
    <chr>         <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>     
  1 > 40          NaOH        0              1     
  2 > 40          NaOH        0              2     
  3 > 40          NaOH        0              3     
  4 > 40          NaOH        0              4     
  5 > 40          NaOH        0              5     
 39 > 40          NaOH        8              1    
 40 > 40          NaOH        8              2     
 41 > 40          NaOH        8              3     

105 <60           NaOH        0              1     
106 <60           NaOH        0              2     
107 <60           NaOH        0              3     
131 <60           NaOH        5              2     
132 <60           NaOH        5              4
```

What I want is an additional column that counts the total Volume over all days for each `Particle_Size`. Like that:

```
Particle_Size Titrant       Day     Volume_titrant  Volume_total
    <chr>         <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>
  1 > 40          NaOH        0              1     1
  2 > 40          NaOH        0              2     2
  3 > 40          NaOH        0              3     3
  4 > 40          NaOH        0              4     4
  5 > 40          NaOH        0              5     5
 39 > 40          NaOH        8              1     6
 40 > 40          NaOH        8              2     7
 41 > 40          NaOH        8              3     8

105 <60           NaOH        0              1     1
106 <60           NaOH        0              2     2
107 <60           NaOH        0              3     3
131 <60           NaOH        5              2     5
132 <60           NaOH        5              4     9
```

I tried to group my dataset and then mutate a new column with `cumsum()`.
This adds the Volume of several days together and also starts again at 1 with every new Particle_Size. So far so good, but I in the example you see that this doesn't count the Volume as I want it.

```
df = na.omit()%>%
     group_by(Particle_Size, Titrant)%>%
     mutate(Total_Volume = cumsum(Volume_titrant))
```

```
Particle_Size Titrant       Day     Volume_titrant   Cumsum
    <chr>         <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>
  1 > 40          NaOH        0              1     1
  2 > 40          NaOH        0              2     3
  3 > 40          NaOH        0              3     6
  4 > 40          NaOH        0              4     10
  5 > 40          NaOH        0              5     15
 39 > 40          NaOH        8              1     16
 40 > 40          NaOH        8              2     18
 41 > 40          NaOH        8              3     21

105 <60           NaOH        0              1     1
106 <60           NaOH        0              2     3
107 <60           NaOH        0              3     6
131 <60           NaOH        5              2     8
132 <60           NaOH        5              4     12
```

Also tried it with `rollsum()` instead of cumsum(), but than I get a problem with the `k` argument. With `k = 1` it just copies the Volume column and with any other `k` I get an error code like this:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Total_Volume`.
x Input `Total_Volume` can't be recycled to size 48.
i Input `Total_Volume` is `rollsum(Volume_titrant, k = 2)`.
i Input `Total_Volume` must be size 48 or 1, not 47.
i The error occurred in group 1: Particle_Size = "<60", Titrant = "NaOH".
```

Is there a function out there or do I need a solution with a loop?
Any ideas?

`enter code here`

Comment: (1) `group_by(Particle_Size, Titrant)` is fine, but you are not feeding it any data. Did you omit the leading `mydata %>%` before that? Or did you intend to use `group_by(mydata, Particle_Size, Titrant)`? (2) If you don't want a cumulative sum, perhaps instead of `mutate` you should use `summarize(Total_Volume = sum(Volume_titrant)`? (3) If you're getting warning/errors, *include them* (or we can't help much). It also helps significantly to provide your expected output (for at least a few rows if not all of your displayed data). Last, please use `dput` to provide sample data. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I forgot some details in trying to make the problem better accessible. The Problem with `summarize(Total_Volume = sum(Volume_titrant)` is that is gives me the sum of each category, but it doesn't  give me the ongoing Volume count in a new column. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Forming a reproducible question can be difficult, but it helps when you try your question in a new empty session. For example, `df = na.omit() %>% ...` errs with `argument "object" is missing, with no default`, because you still have not included the frame name in your data pipe, no effective change from my first comment. I don't think that's your real code; while I really appreciate simplifying code for the sake of reproducible questions on Stack, *the code must still work* in its reduced state.

Comment: And again, *please* provide better data, paste the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sample of your data. It might be `dput(head(df,20))` or it might be a smattering of rows from through the frame. The point is that it is varied enough to show key differences, and contiguous enough to demonstrate the desired effect.

Comment: why row 132 desired output is 9? Whereas the desired output in rows 40 & 41 is 7 & 8 respectively.  Either row 132 should be 7 or rows 40 & 41 should be 8 and 11 respectively?  Your logic is somewhat confusing!  Do you just want to add previous day's last value to current day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have already stated there seems some typo in your desired output. *why row 132 desired output is 9? Whereas the desired output in rows 40 & 41 is 7 & 8 respectively. Either row 132 should be 7 or rows 40 & 41 should be 8 and 11 respectively? Your logic is somewhat confusing! Do you just want to add previous day's last value to current day?*  Try this syntax

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% left_join(df %>% group_by(Particle_Size, Day) %>%
                   summarise(last_val = last(Volume_titrant), .groups = 'drop') %>%
                   group_by(Particle_Size) %>%
                   mutate(last_val = cumsum(lag(last_val, default = 0))), by = c('Particle_Size', 'Day')) %>%
  mutate(desired_value = Volume_titrant + last_val)

#>    Particle_Size Titrant Day Volume_titrant last_val desired_value
#> 1            >40    NaOH   0              1        0             1
#> 2            >40    NaOH   0              2        0             2
#> 3            >40    NaOH   0              3        0             3
#> 4            >40    NaOH   0              4        0             4
#> 5            >40    NaOH   0              5        0             5
#> 6            >40    NaOH   8              1        5             6
#> 7            >40    NaOH   8              2        5             7
#> 8            >40    NaOH   8              3        5             8
#> 9            <60    NaOH   0              1        0             1
#> 10           <60    NaOH   0              2        0             2
#> 11           <60    NaOH   0              3        0             3
#> 12           <60    NaOH   5              2        3             5
#> 13           <60    NaOH   5              4        3             7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `sum()` in a `mutate()` call?

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Particle_Size) %>%
  mutate(Total_valume = sum(Volume_titrant)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 13 x 5
#    Particle_Size Titrant   Day Volume_titrant Total_valume
#            <int> <chr>   <int>          <int>        <int>
#  1            40 NaOH        0              1           21
#  2            40 NaOH        0              2           21
#  3            40 NaOH        0              3           21
#  4            40 NaOH        0              4           21
#  5            40 NaOH        0              5           21
#  6            40 NaOH        8              1           21
#  7            40 NaOH        8              2           21
#  8            40 NaOH        8              3           21
#  9            60 NaOH        0              1           12
# 10            60 NaOH        0              2           12
# 11            60 NaOH        0              3           12
# 12            60 NaOH        5              2           12
# 13            60 NaOH        5              4           12
```